# MS-VPN equivalent for Linux client

Tags: linux, windows, vpn

I have a customer that I connect to via the built-in vpn client in Windows XP.  Occasionally other co-workers do likewise from their workstations.  I'm doing some tidying up and was wondering if there was a simple way to be able to connect to the same vpn endpoint from a Linux desktop.

All I know about their endpoint is that it's some breed of Windows server, so I guess the basic version of my question is:

"accepting that mileage may vary is it generally possible to authenticate with an MS vpn server from a Linux desktop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to a windows server doing pptp via [PPTP Client](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/).  I am not familiar with any of the GUI tools to initiate a pptp connection, but I believe there are a few.